# Batching results SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

How would I go about batching records in a select statement I Have to conserve bandwidth as delaying with shop tills so bandwidth is at a premium. I will be reading the batch size from configuration file and passing to this select statement:

```
Friend Function SelectAllPendingDeliveries() As String Implements iScriptBuilder.SelectAllPendingDeliveries
    Dim retVal As String = ""
    retVal = "Select * from batchtable where [location] is not null and  isprocessed = 0"
    Return retVal
End Function
```

How would I go about doing this is the table structure

@Anthoy I think this is where I am getting tripped up how Would i control it here to for it to loop until the end of the recordset so it executes in batches this is the function that calls the select statement

@Anthory I meen this code i pasted the wrong proc in

```
Friend Function CreateLiveSale(ByVal wrpPush As LiveSales.wrpPush, ByVal rCount As Int32, ByVal request As LiveSales.requestPush, ByVal orderLineData As DataTable, ByVal packetBatchSize As String) ', ByVal orderNumber As String, ByVal orderLineReference As String, ByVal uniqueFilename As String, ByVal tagBarCode As String, ByVal costPrice As String, ByVal deliveryQty As Int32, ByVal orderLineData As DataTable) As Boolean
    Dim retVal As Boolean
    Dim settings As LiveSalesBackOfficeClient.infoLiveSalesBackOfficeClient = _
        (New LiveSalesBackOfficeClient.configurationLoader).LoadConfiguration
    Dim cfb As New cfbConfiguration


    Dim pushOrderIncQTY As New infoPushOrderIncQTY()
    Dim totalRecords As Integer = orderLineData.Rows.Count
    Dim pushOrderInc As List(Of infoPushOrderIncQTY) = New List(Of infoPushOrderIncQTY)() ' create a generic list
    Dim recordCount As Integer = 0
    Dim batchNumber As Integer
    Dim batchNumberpad As String
    Dim filenameSplit As String()



        For Each thisentry In orderLineData.Rows
            If recordCount = 0 Then
                filenameSplit = thisentry.Item("unqiueFilename").ToString().Split("_")
                batchNumber = recordCount + 1

                batchNumberpad = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filenameSplit(2)) & "_" & batchNumber.ToString("D3") & ".csv"
                With request

                    .companyID = settings.companyID

                    .machineID = settings.machineID

                    .uniqueBatchIdentifier = batchNumberpad

                End With

            End If


        With pushOrderIncQTY

            .costPrice = thisentry.Item("costPrice")
            .externalTimeStamp = DateTime.Now()
            .RootPLU = thisentry.Item("tagbarcode") 'set this to the barcode from the file
            .sizeBit = -666
            .supplierID = cfb.SupplierID
            .orderReference = thisentry.Item("OrderNumber")
            .orderLineReference = ""
            .externalTransaction = ""
            .sourceShop = cfb.SiteId 'set to the GEMINI location ID for this store (you will have to get this from your configuration file
            .destinationShop = cfb.SiteId 'set this to the same as the sourceshop
            .QTY = thisentry.Item("ActQty")
            .whichQty = LiveSales.infoPushOrderIncQTY.Which_OrderQty.delivered 'only available option at present

        End With

            recordCount = recordCount + 1


        pushOrderInc.Add(pushOrderIncQTY) ' add it to the list for batching 
        If recordCount = cfb.PacketBatchSize Then ' only when the record count = the packetsize fire off
            pushOrderInc.Clear()
            recordCount = 0
        End If
        If cfb.PacketBatchSize > 0 Then
            CallWebSerivce(wrpPush, request, pushOrderInc.ToArray())

        End If

    Next

        If cfb.PacketBatchSize = 0 Then ' if their is a batch size then lets just processe  
            'call the webservice
        CallWebSerivce(wrpPush, request, pushOrderInc.ToArray())

        End If


    Return retVal

End Function
```

@anthoy the above gets called by this procedure so it does its hear the looping needs to happen

```
     OpenConnection()
            Dim results As DataTable = connection.SqlSelectToDataTable(scriptBuilder.SelectAllPendingDeliveries)
            Dim dataForEmail As String = ""
            Dim msg As String = ""
            msg = "The Following Deliverys where processed for the Following Ordernumbers at " & DateTime.Now.ToString() & Chr(13)
            dataForEmail = "Order Number" & vbTab & "BarCode" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "Product Name" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "Brand" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "Size" & vbTab & vbTab & "Colour" & vbTab & "Qty" & vbTab & vbTab & "RRP" & vbTab & Chr(13)
            Dim totalcost As Decimal
            Dim cnt As Int16 = 0
            Dim fileName As String = ""
            If Not IsNothing(results) AndAlso Not IsNothing(results.Rows) _
            AndAlso results.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Dim rrpprice As Double = 0.0

                For Each thisRow As DataRow In results.Rows

                    If IsDBNull(thisRow.Item("RRPPrice")) Then
                        rrpprice = 0.0
                    Else

                        rrpprice = thisRow.Item("RRPPrice")

                    End If
                    fileName = thisRow.Item("unqiueFilename")
                    totalcost = totalcost + rrpprice * thisRow.Item("QTY")
                    dataForEmail = dataForEmail & BuildReportFoEmail(thisRow)
                    connection.ExecuteNonQuerySql(scriptBuilder.SetDeliveryStatus(2, 1, thisRow.Item("r3DeliveryId")))
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                Next
                connection.ExecuteNonQuerySql(scriptBuilder.SetDeliveryStatus(1, 0))
                CreateLiveSalesDeliveryForR3(cnt, fileName, results, cfb.PacketBatchSize)
                dataForEmail = dataForEmail & vbCrLf & "Total Price " & totalcost.ToString() & vbCrLf & BuildExceptionsForEmail(results) & vbCrLf
            End If
            SendEmailViaWebService(dataForEmail, cfb.EmailForDeliverys, cfb.FullNameForEmailSubject, msg)
            MsgBox("Delvery Complete", vbInformation, "Delivery Import")
            CloseConnection()
```

[image]

Comment: Does your table contain a key?

Comment: @AnthonyHorne one min ill put up the table structure

Comment: @AnthonyHorne their you go anthony sorry my spelling can be bad

Comment: If I understand correctly - Short answer:  add where [r3DeliveryId] > LastbatchID and TOP {config file batch size) to start of query. (No worries on the spelling - I twitch when I see wrong spelling) :)

Comment: If bandwidth is an issue also be aware of whether you need all columns returned or maybe only a few of them.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne its more like paging Anthony first batch return 5 next 10 but say they put in 6 in ini file and their only 5 records how do I account for that

Comment: TOP 6 will only return 5 if there is only five.  Sort of like: "SELECT TOP " + {configbatchsize} + " {fields} from batchtable where [r3DeliveryId] > LastbatchID order by r3DeliveryId

Comment: @AnthonyHorne what should last batch id equate to ?

Comment: I assume that if a Till1 gets records 1 - 5, then the next call (maybe till2) will be 6 - 10, i.e. you need to keep track of the batches themselves?

Comment: Otherwise if there is only one till or concurrency is not a problem, then leave out the "where ..... >LastBatchID) and simply return the batch using top {configfilebatch}.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne it will only be on till 1 but is their no way of doingit like paging would that not be better and more efficencet?

Comment: @DavidB I am not certain I understand.  If till 1 gets 5 records and processes them, the next time the request is made, then those records would have been marked as processed and the next 5 will come through.  OR do you mean you want the object to fetch everything and then send it to the till 5 (or x) at a time?

Comment: @AnthonyHome check above edits I think im getting triped up on how I would call the select statement so that say if a batch of 5 and total records 40 then that means the above code needs to execute 8 times

Comment: @AnthonyHome see code above create live sale

Comment: @AnthonyHome see the calling code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52043/discussion-between-david-b-and-anthony-horne)